# Recommendation for games that I can play with current system

Tags: lubuntu, wine, games, steam, playonlinux

So this is my current system on my laptop:
I have

- Ubuntu 16.04 distribution, 32bit.
- desktop environment : Lubuntu
- 2x Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N2840 @2.16GHz,
- RAM: 2GB.

I have tried to download Steam, but it won't work because of 32bit. I tried installing WineHQ, but am not sure if just downloading a `.exe` game and running it with Wine will do or actually how to do it at all.

I tried `playonlinux`, but it tried to connect to Steam and it probably didn't work out either showing an error, so I am not sure if I can play some game(preferably online) with my setting?
And what exactly do I need to do?

As you might have realized, I am really new to this field.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Any reason for a 32bit system?  Support for 32bit is being potentially killed off soon.

Comment: No reason whatsoever. However I'm just lazy to switch over. That's why asking if anything possible in current spec. Otherwise Linuxlove>> Windows, and 2gb won't support both properly, so if needed I'll probably bring ubuntu64bit. How much will ubuntu64bit help?

Comment: Steam can install on 32-bit Linux, but yeah it can be difficult. Can you share the specific error output? It's usually pointing to some missing dependencies, and then it's fine after they're installed, but those can also be an issue to get installed at times. Lol.

Comment: Steam installs properly, it's on my laptop but it doesn't work, when I try to login or load anything basically. 'playonlinux' also didn't work when I tried to install 'Assassin's Creed', there was some problem because steam couldn't connect properly.

Comment: One of my favorite games, SuperTuxKart, should be able to run on 32-bit systems just fine.  You may have to turn down the graphical effects though.  https://launchpad.net/~stk/+archive/ubuntu/dev

Comment: Though I recommend upgrading to (L)ubuntu 18.04 64-bit if possible.  Also, check if your RAM and processor can be upgraded.  My current laptop came with a 2nd-gen dual-core Celeron and 4GB of ram, but I upgraded to a 3rd-gen Core i5 and 8GB of RAM for relatively cheap (about $50 for the processor).  Could you post the model number of your laptop?

Comment: It's Acer-Aspire-ES1-512.

Comment: @QwertyChouskie Are you saying you got a  3rd-gen Core i5 and 8GB of RAM for $50 ? :O

Comment: The processor was ~$50, the RAM was pulled from another system (the laptop came with 1 4GB stick, the extra 4GB stick was added in the second slot).

Comment: Any reason of down-voting the question, to whomsoever it may concern? Does it violate any rules of this website?